# How do I make entity reference breadcrumbs?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I need to make entity reference breadcrumbs, with the first level being a node title, and the second level the title of a referred node.

As you can see in the image below, the nodes are different content types.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

How do I make entity reference breadcrumbs?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @No Sssweat You can answer this question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**0)** download and enable the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module

**1)** Go to eLesson content type Manage Fields.

**2)** Add a new field, call it "File Under" select  Entity Reference as your type and use auto complete as your widget.

[image]

**3)** Select Node as your Target Type

- Target Bundles: checkmark Course only

[image]

### **4)** Go to your Forex Advantage node and edit it.

- For **File Under** type Beg, and select BEGINNERS COURSE.
- Save changes.

**5)** If you have any breadcrumbs module, disable it and uninstall it.

- Install [Crumbs, the Breadcrumbs suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/crumbs) Module
- Enable Crumbs only (no need to enable Crumbs Example nor Crumbs Lab)

**6)** Since there is no configuration link, the only way to access the config is by going to it directly, so to go `www.yourwebsite.com/admin/structure/crumbs`

**7)** Under Disabled by default, drag up the entityreference.* to Enabled.

[image]

- Save Changes

8) Go to your Forex Advantage node and now you should see

BEGGINERS COURSE >> Forex Advantage

Comment: “Entity Reference” does not exist in FILE TYPE

Comment: oh, sorry missed a step, you need to download the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module

Comment: 4) Go to your Forex Advantage node and edit it.
   For File Under put BEGINNERS COURSE
   Save changes.---->I don't understand what it means.

Comment: #1 Go to your Forex Advantage page. #2 click edit button #3 For File Under put BEGINNERS COURSE #4 Click save button.

Comment: by the way, in Drupal: **node = page**

Comment: I did't it ,but it's not work!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31341/discussion-between-wuchuan-and-no-sssweat).

Comment: you must of done something wrong. Did you save changes in step 7?

Comment: yes.I saved it，I give you a screenshot

Comment: perhaps, you need to Clear the cache `/admin/config/development/performance` click on clear all caches

Comment: ok ok I see where the error is. In File Under, type `Beg` and you should see it shows you an option for BEGINNERS COURSE, click on it, now you should see something like this BEGINNER COURSE (8)  <--- note your number is probably not 8, but that's ok, don't worry about that. Then click save.

Comment: Go To eLesson content type Manage Fields. Maybe it's better if you change the File Under widget from autocomplete to select list.

Comment: Now only show:Home » BEGINNERS COURSE;

Comment: ok ok if I have a problem, I will ask you for advice.:)

Comment: Just saying, instead of entityreference.* you maybe only want to enable entityreference.field_file_under.*. This way you avoid that other entityreference fields have any effect on the breadcrumb.